# linkedin company search API multiple facets?

Tags: python, api, linkedin-api

In the new API documentation it's written that to use a facet you add it in the url this way `"&facet=location,us:0,fr:0"` but it's not written anywhere how to specify multiple facets.

What I am trying to do is to limit my search results by `industry` and `location`.

These are my attempts:

```
application.search_company(selectors=[{'companies':
                 ['industries','locations']}],
                  params={'count':100,'universal-name':'linkedin','facet':'location,us:84','facet':'company-size,H',
                'facet':'industry,43'}))#doesnt work it just picks the last one
```

I also tried:

```
application.search_company(selectors=[{'companies':
             ['industries','locations']}],
              params={'count':100,'universal-name':'linkedin',
              'facet':'company-size,H,industry,43'}))#didnt work ignored industry
```

and this:

```
application.search_company(selectors=[{'companies':
             ['industries','locations']}],
              params={'count':100,'universal-name':'linkedin',
              'facets':['company-size,H','industry,43']}))#didnt work (error)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the last one is correct, you just need to use facet not facets
in the page you specified "https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/company-search"

facets is the output you get from the request while facet is the input.